# Was metallurgy of Zinc first started in India?

Tags: india, materials-science

I have heard many people talk about this, is there any proof available?

Comment: Did you at least try to do the obvious google search for `zinc metallurgy india`? It yields [this wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_metallurgy_in_South_Asia) which has some useful information as well as links to other sources. Did you have a look at these? What about them was unclear? Currently, it seems like you did not put much effort into researching this question.

Answer (score 1):

Zinc is principally known anciently from the production of brass which was widespread in the ancient world. The way that brass is made is that copper is combined with calamine (zinc oxide, a common mineral) and then reduced in situ with charcoal. Most ancient civilizations that had well-developed copper metallurgy readily discovered how to make brass as well, which involves the utilization of zinc. For example, among the ancient Greeks bronze (copper and tin) was known as "kalchon" and brass was known as "orikalchon".

In India, there has always been a strong knowledge of copper and its uses, which of course involves the production of brass. However, to say that zinc was first used in India or was exclusively discovered in India is probably incorrect.